# How to dismiss dialog fragment started via Android Navigation library

Tags: android-architecture-navigation

In [Navigation 2.1.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha03) they added functionality to navigate to a DialogFragment with `<dialog>` tag.

However, how can the source fragment/activity then dismiss this dialog fragment? Its very easy to do this in pure AOSP android with [`dialogFragment.dismiss()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#dismiss()), but I don't see an accompanying way in Navigation library.

Answer (score 7):

`findNavController().navigateUp()` is the one what you are looking for.

`<dialog>` is treated same as `<fragment>`. Controlling destinations are all identical.